# При парсинге XML выводится некорректный URL картинки

Tags: php, xml

Есть код:

```
<?php if ($this->checkPosition('image')) {
if (is_array($item_params['picture'][$item->id])) {
foreach ($item_params['picture'][$item->id] as $image) {
echo '<picture>' . $image . "</picture>\n ";
}
}
}?>
```

При этом `$item_params = array ('picture' => $picture)`

Результатом выполнения становится строка в XML файле в которой значится URL на картинку в тэгах `<picture></picture>`

Выглядит это следующим образом:

```
<picture>http://site.com/images/category/art-1/logo/image.jpg</picture>
```

Как видно из URL, по структуре, в папке art-1 лежит папка logo. Но этого не должно отображаться в результате парсинга.

**Суть вопроса в следующем:**

Что неправильно в моем коде? Почему в URL попадает конечная папка из директории, а на та что указана в настройках галереи?

У позиции `'image'` есть четко настроенная ссылка, это ссылка на галерею по адресу - `(http://site.com/images/category/art-1/)`

**Как должен выглядеть правильный результат?**

1. Необходимо чтобы по выполнению кода, в тэгах `<picture></picture>` отсутствовала папка logo.
2. В тэгах `<picture></picture>`, были ссылки на все файлы из галереи, через запятую:

   `<picture>
   http://site.com/images/category/art-1/image-1.jpg,
   http://site.com/images/category/art-1/image-2.jpg,
   http://site.com/images/category/art-1/image-3.jpg
   </picture>`

Спасибо!

Comment: из приведенного кода ничего не понятно. Вы показываете нам некий магический `$item_params['picture'][$item->id]`, о котором нам ничего не известно, и спрашиваете "почему в нем лежит не то, что мне надо?".  Приведенный-то фрагмент кода работает: что ему дали, то он и выводит.

Comment: Очень разумное замечание, которое ткнуло в направление "раскопок", сижу смотрю, что есть `$item_params`. Спасибо!